# How to put bluetooth prompt on notification bar when receiving files [incoming file no option to select yes or no]?

Tags: notifications, bluetooth, notification-bar

Okay, I'm not sure how to phrase this question but what I am trying to achieve is to have a bluetooth transfer prompt right on the notification shade instead of having to pull down, then tap on the transfer request.

I think images will work best to describe what I'm trying to achieve. Here is how it appears on my primary device (Redmi Note 4, MIUI 9):

[image: IMG:]

I want it to appear on the notification bar like this:

[image: IMG:]

Basically I want the **accept** or **decline** prompt right on the notification bar, rather than tapping the notification first. (Any methods welcome, I have Tasker if its needed) or even third-party apps are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was more of a ROM issue, couldn't bother to find a workaround but it was fixed in later versions of the MIUI ROM:

[image]